# nonhomogenous and homogenous linear equations: non-specific solution

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, finite-fields

Given the linear equations, over the field of $5$, so only numbers $0,1,2,3,4$ "exists" :

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 & 3 \\
    3 & 2 & 2 \\
    3 & 0 & 2 \\
    \end{matrix} \right| 
\left. \begin{matrix} 1\\3\\2 \end{matrix} \right)$$

I have found a specific solution after forming the above into:

$$\left(\begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 & 3 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0 \\
    \end{matrix} \right| 
\left. \begin{matrix} 1\\3\\0 \end{matrix} \right)$$

with $z=0, y=3, x=4$.

What I struggle with is finding the non-specific solution. I have thought about just putting in the zero vector on the right hand site of my equations, but then I struggle to find a usable solution.

Comment: What is “the non-specific solution”?

Comment: Also the set $\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ is NOT a field.

Comment: Well I see the problem; those two matrices are not row equivalent.

Comment: Thanks for the replies and apologies for misusing terms then. I translate from German and according to wiki a "Körper" is a mathematical field.

Nonetheless, I struggle to find a methodical approach to the solution here. I understand somewhat that z is free, so let's put z=1. How do I approach the rest of

2x 1y = 0 and 
0x 1y = 0

where I suppose that y=0 due to the 2nd equation? Or is my right hand side wrong on the top equation?

Answer (score 1):

So for the non-specific solution, I guess I have to first make the right hand side of my equation to the zero vector, so from

$$
\begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 & 3 &|&1\\
    0 & 1 & 0 &|&3\\
    0 & 0 & 0 &|&0\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

I have

$$
\begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 & 3 &|&0\\
    0 & 1 & 0 &|&0\\
    0 & 0 & 0 &|&0\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Then I set the one free variable (rank of 2 and 3 variables: 3-2=1), and say z=1

$$
\begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 & 3*1 &|&0\\
    0 & 1 & 0*1 &|&0\\
    0 & 0 & 0*1 &|&0\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

and move z to the right hand side of my equation:

$$
\begin{matrix}
    2 & 1 &|&2*\\
    0 & 1 &|&0\\
    \end{matrix}
$$

*=2 because of -3 in F5 is 2.

and then I just solve it again for x and y. So I get y=0, x=1

and solution is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}4\\3\\0\end{bmatrix}+λ\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$

My remaining question (if what I did is correct) to this is: When do I know when to specifically set numbers instead of letters? As in, I set z=1. When am I supposed to set free variables to say α and β and calculate with that? Do I have to check solvability or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Same method as in $\mathbf R$,  with computations done  in $\mathbf F_5$: transform to the reduced row echelon form:
\begin{align}
\begin{bmatrix}\hskip-0.5em\begin{array}{ccc|c}
2&1&3&1\newline 3&2&2&3\newline 3&0&2&2
\end{array}\hskip-0.5em\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow[R_i\to 2R_i\ (i=2,3)]{R_1\to3R_1}
& \begin{bmatrix}\hskip-0.5em\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&3&4&3\newline 1&4&4&1\newline 1&0&4&4
\end{array}\hskip-0.5em\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow[R_3-R_1\to R_3]{R_2-R_1\to R_2}
\begin{bmatrix}\hskip-0.5em\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&3&4&3\newline 0&1&0&3\newline 0&2&0&1
\end{array}\hskip-0.5em\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow[R_3+3R_2\to R_3]{R_1+2R_2\to R_1} %\\
\begin{bmatrix}\hskip-0.5em\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&0&4&4\newline 0&1&0&3\newline 0&0&0&0
\end{array}\hskip-0.5em\end{bmatrix}
\end{align} so the solutions are
$$\begin{bmatrix}4\\3\\0\end{bmatrix}-z\begin{bmatrix}4\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}4\\3\\0\end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: All I see in your answer in the above reduction is what I already have for the specific solution and then under it you post the complete solution to it without any explanation (or I just don't see it yet). The jump from the above to that under - specifically where the z*(1,0,1) comes from - isn't clear to me still.

edit: Do I have to somehow take the zero vector and subtract the (3,0,0) column from it (or in this case only the (3,0)) to get the right hand side of my homogenous linear equation?